# What's the best way to align the PublishingPageImage on the right top corner of the news article?

Tags: page-layout, image

I am creating my custom page layout. I am struggeling with the picture align. I would like to show it in the right top corner of my news article text.

Something like this:

[image]

I try this already:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField ID="newsArticleImage" runat="server" FieldName="PublishingPageImage" RenditionId="6" CssClass="newsArticleImage" />
                <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" runat="server"/>
```

In my custom css I align by the class "newsArticleImage" to the right. But In the rendered html I do not see the class "newsArticleImage" on my picture.

How to align the control to the right? It looks like the CssClass property is not working.

**UPDATE**

You see the control "PublishingPageContent" where you will see my news article text. In the text I would like to have in the right top corner the control "PublishingPageImage".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally understand your problem here since you can put the control every where on your page and use CSS to place it.

Comment: See my update. These are 2 controls. I don't now how to show the second control inside the text of the first control.

Comment: Your requirement is the same as Right Image Page Layout, you might have a look at this to see how they place controls by download it and open with your familiar editor.